# execvp is not accepting all the argument list from ps -u command

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to read the all the PID from already executing processes with a specific name, saving does PID for later kill does process with a signal alarm every 45 seconds.

The problem comes when executing the execvp with the following parameters:

```
char* command = "ps";
char* argument_list[] = {"ps ", "-u|grep 'NAME_PROCESS'|grep -v 'grep'|awk '{print $2}'", NULL};

int status_code = execvp(command, argument_list);
```

The error that shows up is the following:

> ```
> error: user name does not exist
>
> Usage:
>  ps  [options]
>
>  Try 'ps  --help <simple|list|output|threads|misc|all>'
>   or 'ps  --help <s|l|o|t|m|a>'
>  for additional help text.
>
> For more details see ps(1).
> ```

Comment: Using `|` is part of the shell, and can't be done with just execvp. You either need to use `system()` or launch multiple processes and connect the stdout of the each process to the stdin of the next process.

Comment: To run the `ps | grep | grep | awk` pipeline (which is an anti-pattern, BTW.  You should never pipe `grep` to `awk`), the shell will spawn 4 processes.  One for `ps`, one for each`grep`, and one for `awk`.  To simulate that, you should fork/exec 4 times.

Answer (score 1):

You can use shell metacharacters but you need to invoke the shell explicitly and pass the entire command line as a single string (untested)...

```
const char *command = "sh";
char *argument_list[] = {
    "sh", "-c", "ps -u | grep 'NAME_PROCESS' | grep -v 'grep' | awk '{print $2}'", NULL
};
execvp(command, argument_list);
```

Comment: @AlejandroFerrer, please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)!