# QT plain command execution like system

Tags: c++, bash, qt

I have a pretty complicate command list, which loads a virtual env and executes several commands on a given text. It works fine with system() but fails with QProcess::execute. This is a bummer since I want to use

```
QProcess process; 
process.readAllStandardOutput();
```

to read the output without messing with pipes. Is there a way to give a process just a "stupid" command string, which it executes like system() ?

```
command = "bash -c \"" + prepend + "\\\"" +  text + "\\\"" + append + "\"";

std::cout << command.toStdString().c_str() << std::endl;

//qDebug() << QProcess::execute(command.toStdString().c_str());
system(command.toStdString().c_str());
```

QT seems to mess up the parameters:

```
usage: program_name [-h] [--list_models [LIST_MODELS]] [--text TEXT]
```

Edit1: solution with popen (ugly but working):

```
FILE *fp;
char path[1035];
fp = popen(command.toStdString().c_str(), "r");
if (fp == NULL)
{
    printf("Failed to run command\n" );
    exit(1);
}

while (fgets(path, sizeof(path), fp) != NULL)
{
    QString line = path;
    if(line.contains("Keyword"))
    {
        qDebug() << "=============================";
        qDebug() << line;
        qDebug() << "=============================";
    }
}

pclose(fp);
```

Edit2: Requested debug output

```
programm_name started
bash -x -c "source /home/myusername/anaconda3/bin/activate; conda activate myenv; programm_name --text \"test\" --model_name tts_models/en/ljspeech/tacotron2-DCA --vocoder_name vocoder_models/en/ljspeech/mulitband-melgan --out_path /home/myusername/projects/tts/soundoutput/"
+ unset _mlre _mlIFS _mlshdbg
+ '[' 0 = 1 ']'
+ '[' -n x ']'
+ _mlIFS='  
'
+ IFS=' '
+ '[' -n '' ']'
++ /usr/bin/tclsh /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/modulecmd.tcl bash autoinit
+ eval 'module()' '{
' unset _mlre _mlIFS '_mlshdbg;
' if '[' '"${MODULES_SILENT_SHELL_DEBUG:-0}"' = ''\''1'\''' '];' 'then
' case '"$-"' 'in
' '*v*x*)' set '+vx;' '_mlshdbg='\''vx'\''' ';;
' '*v*)' set '+v;' '_mlshdbg='\''v'\''' ';;
' '*x*)' set '+x;' '_mlshdbg='\''x'\''' ';;
' '*)' '_mlshdbg='\'''\''' ';;
' 'esac;
' 'fi;
' if '[' -n '"${IFS+x}"' '];' 'then
' '_mlIFS=$IFS;
' 'fi;
' 'IFS='\''' ''\'';
' for _mlv in '${MODULES_RUN_QUARANTINE:-};' 'do
' if '[' '"${_mlv}"' = '"${_mlv##*[!A-Za-z0-9_]}"' -a '"${_mlv}"' = '"${_mlv#[0-9]}"' '];' 'then
' if '[' -n '"`eval' ''\''echo' '${'\''$_mlv'\''+x}'\''`"' '];' 'then
' '_mlre="${_mlre:-}${_mlv}_modquar='\''`eval' ''\''echo' '${'\''$_mlv'\''}'\''`'\''' '";
' 'fi;
' '_mlrv="MODULES_RUNENV_${_mlv}";
' '_mlre="${_mlre:-}${_mlv}='\''`eval' ''\''echo' '${'\''$_mlrv'\'':-}'\''`'\''' '";
' 'fi;
' 'done;
' if '[' -n '"${_mlre:-}"' '];' 'then
' '_mlre="eval' '${_mlre}";
' 'fi;
' eval '`${_mlre:-}/usr/bin/tclsh' /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/modulecmd.tcl bash '$*`;
' '_mlstatus=$?;
' if '[' -n '"${_mlIFS+x}"' '];' 'then
' 'IFS=$_mlIFS;
' 'else
' unset 'IFS;
' 'fi;
' if '[' -n '"${_mlshdbg:-}"' '];' 'then
' set '-$_mlshdbg;
' 'fi;
' unset _mlre _mlv _mlrv _mlIFS '_mlshdbg;
' return '$_mlstatus;
};
MODULES_CMD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/modulecmd.tcl;' export 'MODULES_CMD;
MODULESHOME=/usr/share/modules;' export 'MODULESHOME;
test' '0;'
++ MODULES_CMD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/modulecmd.tcl
++ export MODULES_CMD
++ MODULESHOME=/usr/share/modules
++ export MODULESHOME
++ test 0
+ '[' -n x ']'
+ IFS='     
'
+ unset _mlIFS
+ unset _mlre _mlv _mlrv
+ '[' 0 = 1 ']'
+ '[' -t 1 ']'
+ export -f module
+ export -f switchml
+ ENV=/usr/share/modules/init/profile.sh
+ export ENV
+ BASH_ENV=/usr/share/modules/init/bash
+ export BASH_ENV
+ '[' 4 -ge 3 ']'
+ [[ hxBc =~ i ]]
+ [[ ! :/usr/lib/qt5/bin:/usr/bin:/home/myusername/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin: =~ :/usr/bin: ]]
++ manpath
+ manpath=/usr/share/man:/usr/local/man:/usr/local/share/man
+ [[ ! :/usr/share/man:/usr/local/man:/usr/local/share/man: =~ :/usr/share/man: ]]
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ source /home/myusername/anaconda3/bin/activate
++ _CONDA_ROOT=/home/myusername/anaconda3
++ . /home/myusername/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
+++ export CONDA_EXE=/home/myusername/anaconda3/bin/conda
+++ CONDA_EXE=/home/myusername/anaconda3/bin/conda
+++ export _CE_M=
+++ _CE_M=
+++ export _CE_CONDA=
+++ _CE_CONDA=
+++ export CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=/home/myusername/anaconda3/bin/python
+++ CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=/home/myusername/anaconda3/bin/python
+++ '[' -z '' ']'
+++ export CONDA_SHLVL=0
+++ CONDA_SHLVL=0
+++ '[' -n '' ']'
+++++ dirname /home/myusername/anaconda3/bin/conda
++++ dirname /home/myusername/anaconda3/bin
+++ PATH=/home/myusername/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/lib/qt5/bin:/usr/bin:/home/myusername/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
+++ export PATH
+++ '[' -z '' ']'
+++ PS1=
++ conda activate
++ '[' 1 -lt 1 ']'
++ local cmd=activate
++ shift
++ case "$cmd" in
++ __conda_activate activate
++ '[' -n '' ']'
++ local cmd=activate
++ shift
++ local ask_conda
++ CONDA_INTERNAL_OLDPATH=/home/myusername/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/lib/qt5/bin:/usr/bin:/home/myusername/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
++ __add_sys_prefix_to_path
++ '[' -n '' ']'
+++ dirname /home/myusername/anaconda3/bin/conda
++ SYSP=/home/myusername/anaconda3/bin
+++ dirname /home/myusername/anaconda3/bin
++ SYSP=/home/myusername/anaconda3
++ '[' -n '' ']'
++ PATH=/home/myusername/anaconda3/bin:/home/myusername/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/lib/qt5/bin:/usr/bin:/home/myusername/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
++ export PATH
+++ PS1=
+++ /home/myusername/anaconda3/bin/conda shell.posix activate
++ ask_conda='PS1='\''(base) '\''
export PATH='\''/home/myusername/anaconda3/bin:/home/myusername/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/lib/qt5/bin:/usr/bin:/home/myusername/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin'\''
export CONDA_PREFIX='\''/home/myusername/anaconda3'\''
export CONDA_SHLVL='\''1'\''
export CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV='\''base'\''
export CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER='\''(base) '\''
export CONDA_EXE='\''/home/myusername/anaconda3/bin/conda'\''
export _CE_M='\'''\''
export _CE_CONDA='\'''\''
export CONDA_PYTHON_EXE='\''/home/myusername/anaconda3/bin/python'\'''
++ rc=0
++ PATH=/home/myusername/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/lib/qt5/bin:/usr/bin:/home/myusername/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
++ eval 'PS1='\''(base) '\''
export PATH='\''/home/myusername/anaconda3/bin:/home/myusername/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/lib/qt5/bin:/usr/bin:/home/myusername/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin'\''
export CONDA_PREFIX='\''/home/myusername/anaconda3'\''
export CONDA_SHLVL='\''1'\''
export CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV='\''base'\''
export CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER='\''(base) '\''
export CONDA_EXE='\''/home/myusername/anaconda3/bin/conda'\''
export _CE_M='\'''\''
export _CE_CONDA='\'''\''
export CONDA_PYTHON_EXE='\''/home/myusername/anaconda3/bin/python'\'''
+++ PS1='(base) '
+++ export PATH=/home/myusername/anaconda3/bin:/home/myusername/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/lib/qt5/bin:/usr/bin:/home/myusername/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
+++ PATH=/home/myusername/anaconda3/bin:/home/myusername/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/lib/qt5/bin:/usr/bin:/home/myusername/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
+++ export CONDA_PREFIX=/home/myusername/anaconda3
+++ CONDA_PREFIX=/home/myusername/anaconda3
+++ export CONDA_SHLVL=1
+++ CONDA_SHLVL=1
+++ export CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=base
+++ CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=base
+++ export 'CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER=(base) '
+++ CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER='(base) '
+++ export CONDA_EXE=/home/myusername/anaconda3/bin/conda
+++ CONDA_EXE=/home/myusername/anaconda3/bin/conda
+++ export _CE_M=
+++ _CE_M=
+++ export _CE_CONDA=
+++ _CE_CONDA=
+++ export CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=/home/myusername/anaconda3/bin/python
+++ CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=/home/myusername/anaconda3/bin/python
++ '[' 0 '!=' 0 ']'
++ __conda_hashr
++ '[' -n '' ']'
++ '[' -n '' ']'
++ hash -r
+ conda activate myenv
+ '[' 2 -lt 1 ']'
+ local cmd=activate
+ shift
+ case "$cmd" in
+ __conda_activate activate myenv
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ local cmd=activate
+ shift
+ local ask_conda
+ CONDA_INTERNAL_OLDPATH=/home/myusername/anaconda3/bin:/home/myusername/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/lib/qt5/bin:/usr/bin:/home/myusername/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
+ __add_sys_prefix_to_path
+ '[' -n '' ']'
++ dirname /home/myusername/anaconda3/bin/conda
+ SYSP=/home/myusername/anaconda3/bin
++ dirname /home/myusername/anaconda3/bin
+ SYSP=/home/myusername/anaconda3
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ PATH=/home/myusername/anaconda3/bin:/home/myusername/anaconda3/bin:/home/myusername/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/lib/qt5/bin:/usr/bin:/home/myusername/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
+ export PATH
++ PS1='(base) '
++ /home/myusername/anaconda3/bin/conda shell.posix activate myenv
+ ask_conda='PS1='\''(myenv) '\''
export PATH='\''/home/myusername/anaconda3/envs/myenv/bin:/home/myusername/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/lib/qt5/bin:/usr/bin:/home/myusername/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin'\''
export CONDA_PREFIX='\''/home/myusername/anaconda3/envs/myenv'\''
export CONDA_SHLVL='\''2'\''
export CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV='\''myenv'\''
export CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER='\''(myenv) '\''
export CONDA_EXE='\''/home/myusername/anaconda3/bin/conda'\''
export _CE_M='\'''\''
export _CE_CONDA='\'''\''
export CONDA_PYTHON_EXE='\''/home/myusername/anaconda3/bin/python'\''
export CONDA_PREFIX_1='\''/home/myusername/anaconda3'\''
. "/home/myusername/anaconda3/envs/myenv/etc/conda/activate.d/mpivars.activate.sh"'
+ rc=0
+ PATH=/home/myusername/anaconda3/bin:/home/myusername/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/lib/qt5/bin:/usr/bin:/home/myusername/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
+ eval 'PS1='\''(myenv) '\''
export PATH='\''/home/myusername/anaconda3/envs/myenv/bin:/home/myusername/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/lib/qt5/bin:/usr/bin:/home/myusername/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin'\''
export CONDA_PREFIX='\''/home/myusername/anaconda3/envs/myenv'\''
export CONDA_SHLVL='\''2'\''
export CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV='\''myenv'\''
export CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER='\''(myenv) '\''
export CONDA_EXE='\''/home/myusername/anaconda3/bin/conda'\''
export _CE_M='\'''\''
export _CE_CONDA='\'''\''
export CONDA_PYTHON_EXE='\''/home/myusername/anaconda3/bin/python'\''
export CONDA_PREFIX_1='\''/home/myusername/anaconda3'\''
. "/home/myusername/anaconda3/envs/myenv/etc/conda/activate.d/mpivars.activate.sh"'
++ PS1='(myenv) '
++ export PATH=/home/myusername/anaconda3/envs/myenv/bin:/home/myusername/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/lib/qt5/bin:/usr/bin:/home/myusername/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
++ PATH=/home/myusername/anaconda3/envs/myenv/bin:/home/myusername/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/lib/qt5/bin:/usr/bin:/home/myusername/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
++ export CONDA_PREFIX=/home/myusername/anaconda3/envs/myenv
++ CONDA_PREFIX=/home/myusername/anaconda3/envs/myenv
++ export CONDA_SHLVL=2
++ CONDA_SHLVL=2
++ export CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=myenv
++ CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=myenv
++ export 'CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER=(myenv) '
++ CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER='(myenv) '
++ export CONDA_EXE=/home/myusername/anaconda3/bin/conda
++ CONDA_EXE=/home/myusername/anaconda3/bin/conda
++ export _CE_M=
++ _CE_M=
++ export _CE_CONDA=
++ _CE_CONDA=
++ export CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=/home/myusername/anaconda3/bin/python
++ CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=/home/myusername/anaconda3/bin/python
++ export CONDA_PREFIX_1=/home/myusername/anaconda3
++ CONDA_PREFIX_1=/home/myusername/anaconda3
++ . /home/myusername/anaconda3/envs/myenv/etc/conda/activate.d/mpivars.activate.sh
+++ '[' '' '!=' 1 ']'
+++ export I_MPI_ROOT=/home/myusername/anaconda3/envs/myenv
+++ I_MPI_ROOT=/home/myusername/anaconda3/envs/myenv
+++ '[' -z '' ']'
+++ export CLASSPATH=/home/myusername/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/mpi.jar
+++ CLASSPATH=/home/myusername/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/mpi.jar
+++ '[' -z '' ']'
++++ manpath
+++ export MANPATH=/home/myusername/anaconda3/envs/myenv/share/man:/home/myusername/anaconda3/envs/myenv/man:/home/myusername/anaconda3/man:/usr/share/man:/usr/local/man:/usr/local/share/man
+++ MANPATH=/home/myusername/anaconda3/envs/myenv/share/man:/home/myusername/anaconda3/envs/myenv/man:/home/myusername/anaconda3/man:/usr/share/man:/usr/local/man:/usr/local/share/man
+++ '[' -z '' ']'
+++ i_mpi_ofi_library_internal=1
+++ case "$i_mpi_ofi_library_internal" in
+++ export PATH=/home/myusername/anaconda3/envs/myenv/bin/libfabric:/home/myusername/anaconda3/envs/myenv/bin:/home/myusername/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/lib/qt5/bin:/usr/bin:/home/myusername/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
+++ PATH=/home/myusername/anaconda3/envs/myenv/bin/libfabric:/home/myusername/anaconda3/envs/myenv/bin:/home/myusername/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/lib/qt5/bin:/usr/bin:/home/myusername/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
+++ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/myusername/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/libfabric:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
+++ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/myusername/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/libfabric:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
+++ '[' -z '' ']'
+++ export LIBRARY_PATH=/home/myusername/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/libfabric
+++ LIBRARY_PATH=/home/myusername/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/libfabric
+++ export FI_PROVIDER_PATH=/home/myusername/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/libfabric/prov:/usr/lib64/libfabric
+++ FI_PROVIDER_PATH=/home/myusername/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/libfabric/prov:/usr/lib64/libfabric
+ '[' 0 '!=' 0 ']'
+ __conda_hashr
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ hash -r
+ programm_name --text 'test --model_name' tts_models/en/ljspeech/tacotron2-DCA --vocoder_name vocoder_models/en/ljspeech/mulitband-melgan --out_path /home/myusername/projects/tts/soundoutput/
2022-01-05 14:51:05.187922: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
usage: programm_name [-h] [--list_models [LIST_MODELS]] [--text TEXT]
           [--model_name MODEL_NAME] [--vocoder_name VOCODER_NAME]
           [--config_path CONFIG_PATH] [--model_path MODEL_PATH]
           [--out_path OUT_PATH] [--use_cuda USE_CUDA]
           [--vocoder_path VOCODER_PATH]
           [--vocoder_config_path VOCODER_CONFIG_PATH]
           [--speakers_json SPEAKERS_JSON] [--speaker_idx SPEAKER_IDX]
           [--gst_style GST_STYLE] [--save_spectogram SAVE_SPECTOGRAM]
programm_name: error: unrecognized arguments: tts_models/en/ljspeech/tacotron2-DCA
2
```

Comment: Try to add `-x` before `-c` and tell us what you get.

Comment: added debug output to the post, it is too long for a comment

Comment: As per [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#execute) you need to pass the program name as the first parameter and all arguments in a string list as the second argument. Also, note that you don't need to (and should not) convert the `QString` to a C-string when using the Qt API. It could be helpful as well to check the return value of `QProcess::execute`. It indicates whether the process could be successfully started or not.

Comment: Looks like you one of your scripts is calling `programm_name` with merged parameters. I.e. `test` and `model_name`.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I prefer to pass several different programs in one go.

Like: 

bash -c "source stuff; conda activate venv; programm1 parameters1, programm2 parameters2; more_stuff;" 

Is this possible in QT? If not I will stay with the popen c code. Ugly but working, I just need an UI to connect some scripts / programms, so I have to type less and can use things like last processed files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out elsewhere the basic problem is that `QProcess` goes to some trouble to *avoid* going through any shell.  Having said that you should be able to achieve what you want by invoking a shell explicitly.

Let's say the command you would usually run under `bash` is `ls -l | grep '\.'` ...

```
QProcess process;
QString shell_command = "ls -l | grep '\.'";
process.start("bash", { "-c", shell_command });
```

Now you can read the command's standard output/error streams as you would with any other `QProcess`.

[Note that this is more or less the `Qt` version of a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70583393/execvp-is-not-accepting-all-the-argument-list-from-ps-u-command).]